# Stop the animation on mouseover using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div where certain controls which are added dynamically after getting data from database.
Its kinda news details that are going to get added. I just wanted that news to scroll automatically which I have achieved through javascript.

Now if I want to stop the animation on mouseover and continue on mouseout how can I modify the javascipt.

This is my html page:

```
<section id="secbody" runat="server" style="position:absolute; background-color:dimgray; max-height:183px; min-height:183%;margin-top:14px;margin-left:545px;width:535px;">

      <div id="galheader" style="width:535px;" runat="server">
         <label id="Label1" style="color:White; position:absolute; font-size:20px; left:20px;  height: 26px; width: 100%;" runat="server"> Upcoming Programs</label> 
</div>

    <section id="secdetails" runat="server" style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype';color:white; min-width:500px;overflow-wrap:break-word;background-attachment:fixed;position:absolute;margin-top:25px;"></section>
    </section>
```

and this is my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            function marqueePlay(){
                $("#secdetails").animate(
                    {
                        top: $("#secbody").height() - $("#secdetails").height(),
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 4000, function(){
                        $("#secdetails").css("top", 1);
                        $("#secdetails").css("opacity", 1);
                        marqueePlay();
                    }
                );
            }
            marqueePlay();

});

    </script>
```

I know we need to use .stop functionality but do not know the proper way to use it.

Comment: have you tried the answer.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy.. I have one more ques.. Can u help me out..

Comment: You see.. I have 2 sections.. secbody and secdetails.. In secbody there is a header and then secdetails.. secdetails will contain all the news.. now when I give this animation it will scroll on the top of secbody and will come out of it.. what I can do if I want the contents of secdetails to disappear within the secdetails when it scrolls to top..

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, then you have to wrap secdetails into another one container. And you have to set its parent css as overflow:hidden.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy.. Exactly sir.. Thats what I was needed.. Thanks alot once again.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.hover()` function to accomplish your task

Try,

```
$("#secdetails").hover(function(){
   $(this).stop(); //Stop the animation when mouse in
},
function(){
   marqueePlay(); //Start the animation when mouse out
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function stopAnimation(){
    $("#secdetails").stop();
}

<div id="secdetails" onmouseout="marqueePlay()" onmouseover="stopAnimation()"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply... but the answer seems correct but I dont know y it did not work.. Anyways.. Thanks for your effort.. :)